# Store value from input field without sending form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to store value from input field in form one. Reason why I need that is when I send form 2 in the same file, all filled input fields in form 1 is blank. My thinking is to read value from form 1 and in form 2 make hidden field with that value. When I send form 2, I can $_POST that hidden field as value in form 1. Now I use jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#search_field').val('<?=$value?>');
    var = $('#search_field').val();
    </script>
```

All works if I in that field echo $_GET value. In some cases I need that, but if $_GET is no set, I need to fill that field by myself. How can I store value what I filled by myself?

First form is search form, what sends data to search engine.
Second form is calendar fields, what specifies time for search results. I have 3 choises - all, 30 days, 10 days. When I click 10 days, then calendar fills out automatic.

Comment: If you're handling 2 forms with one piece of code then you should really only have 1 form.  Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>bla bla 1</form>
<form>bla bla 2</form>
```

No, problem. Depending on what you need.

And if you really have to "submit" data without submitting a form you have to use AJAX/Javascript (OR use a normal link [=GET] for that).